# How to circumvent compatibility warings for pseudo classes?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I inherited an old ASP .NET project, originally written back in 2004. Since then numerous changes & additions have been made to it by competent and incompetent developers.

Whenever I take over a project I tend to clean it up as much as possible. Of course, I can't simply refactor it at will, but if there are changes I can easily make without risking any of the other functionality... One the things I routinely do is to resolve the warnings the code generates in my editor, in this case Visual Studio 2017.

In one of the page I've found the following code snippet:

```
if ($("#<%= SomeCheckbox.SomeID %>").is(":checked")) {
  /* Yada yada */
}
else {
  /* Yada yada */
}
```

This generates the following warning in my Visual Studio (Resharper): "The pseudo-class 'checked' is not compatible with internet explorer 8.0".

At the moment I disabled the warning, but I would prefer to resolve it... What would be a clean way to fix this?

Comment: Personally, I think you're doing more harm than good by antiquing your code to be compatible with a 10 year old browser :)

Comment: I'm not making it compatible, just reworking the code so I no longer have avoidable warnings.

Comment: Also... Internet explorer is still the official browser here... I wouldn't be surprised if IE8 is used by a lot of people.

Comment: *"just reworking the code so I no longer have avoidable warnings."* - I guess I personally see those warnings as a reason to update resharper, not to make code changes. I'm sure there are people who still use IE8, but at some point if you try to play whack-a-mole with IE8 support warnings, you're going to end up sacrificing some of your code-base's readabillity, scalability, efficiency, etc. Such changes end up harming the vast majority of users in an effort to help a very small few. Though, in this instance it doesn't seem to be a big deal, just speaking on browser support in general.

Comment: As a note, IE8 usage is approximately [`0.16%`](https://caniuse.com/usage-table), make of that what you will.

Answer (score 1):

You can substitute `.prop("checked")` for `.is(":checked")`, which should work in IE8 (though hopefully that wouldn't be a practical issue in 2019).

Comment: Yes. The `.prop()` method checks the given property on the DOM node, and the "checked" property is what underlies the meaning of the ":checked" pseudo-class.

Comment: As it turns out, .prop('checked') generates an error. I fixed it using attr('checked')

Comment: @Fysicus out of curiosity, what error? Unless you're using an extremely old version of jQuery, `.prop()` should work fine.